# Vlan between Pfsense and Proxim hotspots

Tags: vlan, pfsense, wifi

[image]

We want to plugin some hotspots to an existing network. Because we will account the hotspot traffic, it is important to route all traffic from the hotspots to the hotspot router.

I tried to do the routing on ip base. This works but is also very easy to trick (by changing the ip address).

Therefore I decided to give vlan a try (which is new terrain for me). On the Pfsense router I made a vlan on the lan side, with tag 20. I also activated the vlan, and made a firewall rule to forward the vlan to the hotspot router.

The Proxim hotspots (AP-4000MR) have several vlan options. My idea is (correct me if I am wrong), that I have to set vlan on the ethernet port. So all clients can connect, and the hotspot tags all outgoing trafic as vlan 20.

The hotspot have several options for vlan on the ethernet port: trunk mode, access mode and mixed mode. I tried every option/setting, but setting vlan always leads to immediate connection loss to the pfsense router. I am not able to even ping the pfsense router.

Btw: the image is slightly wrong. All wan ports are on separate nic's. All lan traffic comes in on one nic. I have 1 LAN and 4 WAN ports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to enable vlan on the wifi part of the hotspot, and disable vlan on the ethernet port. Now it works as it should.